# How to install Deno on MacOS?

Tags: node.js, macos, deno

Can anyone explain how to install Deno in macOS properly?

Answer (score 1):

Let a package manager like [brew](https://brew.sh/) do the work for you:

```sh
brew install deno
```

Easy to install, easy to upgrade.

Check the [official repo](https://github.com/denoland/deno_install) for all the installation options.

Answer (score 0):

To find the instillation options use official documentation https://deno.land/#installation.

For MacOS following installation options are available.

**01.Using Shell**

```
curl -fsSL https://deno.land/x/install/install.sh | sh
```

**02.Using [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/)**

```
brew install deno
```

**03.Using Cargo (macOS)**

```
cargo install deno
```

Comment: I'm trying the shell option but after it tells me it successfully installed, `deno` is not in my path, even after opening a new `zsh` or terminal. Am I missing something so obvious it's not in the docs? Aha I thought it said it had set the environment variables for me but on closer inspection is says "**Manually add** the directory to your $HOME/.zshrc (or similar)"